# Proper alignment of cases inside align environment

Tags: horizontal-alignment, align

I am using the `rcases` environment inside `align` and would like to have equal signs aligned. How can I achieve that?

Here is what my current tex code looks like

```
\begin{align}
\begin{split}
&\boldsymbol{d}^{\left( 0\right)}   = 0 \\
&\boldsymbol{\phi}^{\left( 0\right)}   = \boldsymbol{\phi}^k \\
&\begin{rcases}
\boldsymbol{d}^{\left( m\right)}   = \beta_m \boldsymbol{D}\boldsymbol{\phi}^{\left(m-1\right)} + \left( 1 - \beta_m \right) \boldsymbol{d}^{\left( m-1\right)} \\
\boldsymbol{\phi}^{\left( m\right)}  = \boldsymbol{\phi}^{\left( 0\right)} + a_m \mathcal{P} \left( \boldsymbol{f} - \boldsymbol{C} \phi^{\left( m-1\right)} - \boldsymbol{d}^{\left( m\right)} - V\frac{3\boldsymbol{\phi}_n^{\left( m-1\right)}-4\boldsymbol{\phi}_{n-1}+\boldsymbol{\phi}_{n-2}}{2\Delta t}\right)
\end{rcases}   m =1,2,\dots, 5  \\
&\boldsymbol{\phi}^{k+1}  = \boldsymbol{\phi}^{\left( 5\right)}
\end{split}
\end{align}
```

And here is the not so nicely aligned result:

[image: Not correctly aligned]

Comment: welcome to tex.sx.  please provide compilable code, beginning with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`.  (this expression is too wide for `article`, so you must be using something else.)  also, not material to the question, instead of the combination of `align` and `split`, a more "conventional" combination would be `equation` and `aligned`, although it doesn't improve the alignment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's ugly, but does the job.  It breaks up the `rcases` environment content, so that an alignment point can be added around the equals sign. That, in and of itself causes issues that have to be remedied with the nonstandard use of `={}&` rather than `&=`, as well as the addition of `\mkern-5mu` to undo `rcases` horizontal padding.

However, in addition, a magic `\vphantom` has to be added to get the `aligned` to the left side of the equation to have the same vertical spacing as the `rcases` on the right side.

EDITED to take Mico's suggestion of removing the excessive `\left...\right` syntax, and of using the `bm` package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools,bm}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\bm{d}^{(0)}   ={}& 0 \\
\bm{\phi}^{( 0)}   ={}& \bm{\phi}^k \\
\begin{aligned}
\bm{d}^{(m)} ={}\\
\bm{\phi}^{(m)} ={}\vphantom{\Bigl(}
\end{aligned}
&
\mkern-5mu\begin{rcases}
   \beta_m \bm{D}\bm{\phi}^{(m-1)} + ( 1 - \beta_m) \bm{d}^{( m-1)} \\
 \bm{\phi}^{(0)} + a_m \mathcal{P} \Bigl( \bm{f} - \bm{C} \phi^{(m-1)} - \bm{d}^{(m)} - V\frac{3\bm{\phi}_n^{(m-1)}-4\bm{\phi}_{n-1}+\bm{\phi}_{n-2}}{2\Delta t}\Bigr)
\end{rcases}   m =1,2,\dots, 5  
\\
\bm{\phi}^{k+1}  ={}& \bm{\phi}^{(5)}
\end{split}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**ORIGINAL ANSWER** (for comparison))

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
\begin{split}
\boldsymbol{d}^{\left( 0\right)}   ={}& 0 \\
\boldsymbol{\phi}^{\left( 0\right)}   ={}& \boldsymbol{\phi}^k \\
\begin{aligned}
\boldsymbol{d}^{\left( m\right)} ={}\\
\boldsymbol{\phi}^{\left( m\right)} ={}\vphantom{\left(\textstyle\frac{x_{n-1}^{(}}{}\right)}
\end{aligned}
&
\mkern-5mu\begin{rcases}
   \beta_m \boldsymbol{D}\boldsymbol{\phi}^{\left(m-1\right)} + \left( 1 - \beta_m \right) \boldsymbol{d}^{\left( m-1\right)} \\
 \boldsymbol{\phi}^{\left( 0\right)} + a_m \mathcal{P} \left( \boldsymbol{f} - \boldsymbol{C} \phi^{\left( m-1\right)} - \boldsymbol{d}^{\left( m\right)} - V\frac{3\boldsymbol{\phi}_n^{\left( m-1\right)}-4\boldsymbol{\phi}_{n-1}+\boldsymbol{\phi}_{n-2}}{2\Delta t}\right)
\end{rcases}   m =1,2,\dots, 5  
\\
\boldsymbol{\phi}^{k+1}  ={}& \boldsymbol{\phi}^{\left( 5\right)}
\end{split}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @giodan You are welcome.  If this answer (if more than one answer are offered) best satisfies the needs of your question, you should consider clicking the check mark to the left of my answer.  That will both give me some quantitative credit, as well as indicate to other readers that this approach you found to be the most suitable.

Comment: A litte too much: `mkern -5mu` is better. And you don't need `split`.

Comment: @Bernard I will incorporate your `\mkern`.  However, the addition of `split` reduces the number of "numbered" equations from 5 to 1, so there is a difference in the result.

Comment: +1. I'd load the `bm` package and use `\bm{...}` instead of `\boldsymbol{...}`. Getting rid of all `\left` and `\right` directives may also be desirable.

Comment: @Steven B. Segletes: I didn't notice the numbering problem. Nevertheless, I find this sort of redundancy  semantically disturbing. I'd prefer `equation+split`…

Comment: @Bernard Fair enough.  Done.

Answer (score 2):

I think using an `rcases` environment gives far too much visual prominence to the `m=1,\dots,5` matter. I suggest using a singled `aligned` environment in an `equation` environment.

Oh, and do get rid of the `\left` and `\right` statements: they achieve nothing at all here except clutter up the code.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,bm}
\usepackage[letterpaper,margin=1in]{geometry} % set page parameters appropriately
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\bm{d}^{(0)}    &= 0 \\
\bm{\phi}^{(0)} &= \bm{\phi}^k \\
\bm{d}^{(m)}    &= \beta_m \bm{D}\bm{\phi}^{(m-1)} + ( 1 - \beta_m ) \bm{d}^{(m-1)},\ 
   m=1,\dots,5 \\
\bm{\phi}^{(m)} &= \bm{\phi}^{(0)} + a_m \mathcal{P} 
  \biggl( \bm{f} - \bm{C} \phi^{(m-1)} - \bm{d}^{(m)} 
  - V\,\frac{3\bm{\phi}_n^{(m-1)}-4\bm{\phi}_{n-1}
  +\bm{\phi}_{n-2}}{2\Delta t}\biggr),\ m=1,\dots,5\\
\bm{\phi}^{k+1} &= \bm{\phi}^{(5)}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1  The spurious `\left...\right` statements do in fact add unwanted spacing effects to the equation, rather than simply doing nothing.

Comment: @AndrewSwann - Thanks! When I wrote "achieve nothing at all", I was thinking mainly about the effects of `\left` and `\right` on the vertical sizes of the associated parentheses. E.g., `(0)` and `\left(0\right)` generate the same vertical sizes for `(` and `)`. I hadn't even thought about the noxious effects of `\left` and `\right` on *horizontal spacing*; those should definitely also be avoided. Very glad you pointed this out!